# non-copy constructor interfering with return from static method

Tags: c++, c++11

How can I have in C++ a static method in a class and a (non-copy) constructor (`const T &t`) so that I can return `t` from the static method?

```
class chunk_t
{
public:
    explicit chunk_t();

    ~chunk_t();

    static chunk_t create_from(const roaring_bitmap_t &data, bool filled = false);

private:
    bool filled = false;
    roaring_bitmap_t *data = nullptr;

    explicit chunk_t(const chunk_t &other);
};

chunk_t::chunk_t()
{
    this->data = roaring_bitmap_create_with_capacity(C);
}

chunk_t::chunk_t(const chunk_t &other)
{
    _ASSERT(other.data != nullptr);

    this->data = roaring_bitmap_copy(other.data);
    this->filled = other.filled;
}

chunk_t chunk_t::create_from(const roaring_bitmap_t &data, bool filled)
{
    chunk_t c;
    c.data = roaring_bitmap_copy(&data);
    c.filled = filled;
    return c; // ERROR: class `chunk_t` has no suitable copy constructor
}

chunk_t::~chunk_t()
{
    if(this->data != nullptr)
    {
        roaring_bitmap_free(this->data);
        this->data = nullptr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do You want/are you able to provide move constructor for Your class? In c++11 I suggest you explicitly delete the constructor with `= delete` instead of making it private, but that's just a sidenote.

Comment: What could be the point of non-copy constructor  `(const T &t)`? In this code example It is actually a constructor that performs a copy, but it is declared `explicit`. It can still be called explicitly like `return chunk_t{c};`.

Comment: So you want a copy constructor that isn't a copy constructor but is a copy constructor, that performs a copy? What's going on exactly?

Comment: what compiler options are you using, and more importantly which compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In c++11, you do not need a copy constructor to return a value; you could provide a move constructor which demonstrates your intent much better as you will continue to have compilation errors on attempts of copy; but you will be able to move your object as and when needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return by value, you *need* a copy (or move) constructor. If you don't want them to be accessible from outside the class you could just declare them `private`.

Other solutions could be:

- Changing your interface to be `init_from(chunk_t& orig, const roaring_bitmap_t &data, bool filled = false)` and initialize an object created with the default constructor.
- Returning a pointer to a new `chunk_t` allocated on the heap.

Comment: "If you want to return by value, you need a copy constructor" no you don't.  You need a copy or move constructor.